# Any other PHP frameworks use a cascading file system?

Tags: kohana, php

I really like the [Kohana cascading file system](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/filesystem).

Do any other PHP frameworks feature this? I want to learn another framework besides Kohana, but I'd love to be able to use the awesomeness of the file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) is the other framework with similar file system. In fact, Kohana was developed and improved from CodeIgniter.

Also, you can find full list of stable php frameworks along with their features here:

[PHP Frameworks](http://phpframeworks.com)

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the original fork, but didn't realise that the cascading was obviously included. Silly me.

Comment: That link doesn't even have Kohana on it! I would of thought it deserved a spot there.

Comment: Unfortunately Kohana still suffers from a lack of exposure =( Also, Alex, you might want to look at Yii also.

Comment: @Russel Dias I might check out Yii. I'm reluctant to look at Code Igniter because I don't like the support for PHP4. I'd rather do everything the PHP5 way.

Comment: It supports it, but only for the application / system folder as CI doesn't support modules like kohana does.

Comment: CI does not have a cascading filesystem, not in the sense that Kohana does. CI relies on using prefixes (`MY_Class`) to create extensions. It does not support modules, all extensions are placed within the application.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you marked Codeigniter as your solution, as it does not have a cascading file system at all. Sure it mimics one with the Controller setup, but it pretty much ends there.

I'm guessing you were either not sure what you were looking for or didn't check to see if Codeigniter actually met your requirement.

Either way, take a look at [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com/), a framework inspired by both Kohana and Codeigniter.

It adopted Kohana's cascading file system and used PHP 5.3's new features such as namespaces, meaning you can't use it on older versions of PHP.

Though it's still very new I've already used it on one project myself and was quite pleased with it. The only thing I didn't like is the ORM they used, which is the same one Kohana uses. It's a strong ORM but it's not very intuitive to use.